# is there a way to locally change the input record separator in perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, file-io, text-processing

Limiting the scope of a variable `$x`  to a particular code chunk or subroutine, by means of `my $x`, saves a coder from a world of "global variable"-caused confusion.

But when it comes to the input record separator, `$/`, apparently its scope cannot be limited.
Am I correct in this?

As a consequence, if I forget to reset the input record separator at the end of a loop, or inside a subroutine, the code **below** my call to the subroutine can give unexpected results.
The following example demonstrates this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $count_records; my $infile = $ARGV[0]; my $HANDLEinfile;

open $HANDLEinfile, '<', $infile or die "cannot open $infile for reading";
$count_records = 0;
while(<$HANDLEinfile>)
{
    $count_records++; 
    print "$count_records:\n";
    print;
}
close $HANDLEinfile;

look_through_other_file();

print "\nNOW, after invoking look_through_other_file:\n";
open $HANDLEinfile, '<', $infile or die "cannot open $infile for reading";
$count_records = 0;
while(<$HANDLEinfile>)
{
    $count_records++; 
    print "$count_records:\n";
    print;
}
close $HANDLEinfile;

sub look_through_other_file
{
    $/ = undef;
    # here, look through some other file with a while loop
    return;
}
```

Here is how it behaves on an input file:

```
> z.pl junk
1:
All work
2:
and
3:
no play
4:
makes Jack a dull boy.

NOW, after invoking look_through_other_file:
1:
All work
and
no play
makes Jack a dull boy.
>
```

Note that if one tries to change to

```
my $/ = undef;
```

inside the subroutine, this generates an error.

Incidentally, among the stackoverflow tags, why is there no tag for "input record separator"?

Comment: It can’t be “my” for the same reason other globals used from ‘discrete external methods’ can’t be — or, can’t be with the desired intent.

Comment: You should never say "this generates an error" and not say what the error was. Even though in this case we can easily figure it out, it is very annoying.

Comment: @TLP, thank you. I will try to remember that in the future. I very much appreciate your replies and comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for the `my $/ = undef;` question is to change it to `local $/ = undef;`. Then the revised code is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $count_records; my $infile = $ARGV[0]; my $HANDLEinfile;

open $HANDLEinfile, '<', $infile or die "cannot open $infile for reading";
$count_records = 0;
while(<$HANDLEinfile>)
{
    $count_records++; 
    print "$count_records:\n";
    print;
}
close $HANDLEinfile;

look_through_other_file();

print "\nNOW, after invoking look_through_other_file:\n";
open $HANDLEinfile, '<', $infile or die "cannot open $infile for reading";
$count_records = 0;
while(<$HANDLEinfile>)
{
    $count_records++; 
    print "$count_records:\n";
    print;
}
close $HANDLEinfile;

sub look_through_other_file
{
    local $/ = undef;
    # here, look through some other file with a while loop
    return;
}
```

Then there is no need to return the input record separator to another value, or to the default, `$/ = "\n";`, by hand.

Comment: Tip: `local $/;` is sufficient to set it to `undef`.

Comment: @ikegami, thank you. I find your replies very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `local` to temporarily update the value of a global variable, including `$/`.

```
sub look_through_other_file {
    local $/ = undef;
    # here, look through some other file with a while loop
    return;
}
```

will use an undefined `$/` as long as the `look_through_other_file` subroutine is in the call stack.

You may encounter this construction in this common idiom, to slurp the entire contents of a file into a variable without altering the value of `$/` for the rest of the program:

```
open my $fh, "<", "/some/file";
my $o = do { local $/; <$fh> };
```

Comment: Bah, no reason to leave `$fh` in score :) `my $o = do { open my $fh, "<", "/some/file"; local $/; <$fh> };`

Comment: Or `my $content = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $filename; <> };`

Comment: @ikegami, what does "score" mean here? Does this metaphorically compare a perl program to a musical score?

Comment: It's a typo for "scope"